# Disable Copy from DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I think this is a simple question.  How do I disable copy from a DataGridView.  It's a silly security feature.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dzbc92t.aspx

Assuming this is Windows Forms, (because that's where the DataGridView is - Asp.NET it's a DataGrid) you can set the ClipboardCopyMode to "disable".

Comment: Yeah, but sometimes finding it among all the other items is the problem.

Comment: That is why two heads are better than one. That is why when you are not playing the game, you can see what moves to make. :O)